# I am getting error: mappings value are not allowed here whenever I am running the yml policy to tag the instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cloudcustodian

I am trying this policy to tag the instance in ec2. I am running this policy by cloud custodian.
help me to solve the issue

```
policies: 
- name:tag_policy   
   resource:ec2   
   actions:     
   - type: tag       
     key:mykey       
     value:myvalue
```

Comment: The issue has been resolved

Comment: Add one space after every colon

Answer (score 1):

I did mistake in the given given that I had written. There must be space after colon so the final code is:

```
policies: 
 - name:tag_policy   
   resource: ec2   
   actions:     
     -type: tag       
      key: mykey       
      value: myvalue
```